# Откуда функция free знает, сколько конкретно байтов памяти освобождать

Tags: c, указатели, память, выделение-памяти

Я новичок в программировании на языке Си. Вопрос по поводу работы функции `free` стандартной библиотеки `stdlib.h`. Допустим, я выделил память для 100 символов:

```
char *pointer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
```

А как грамотно освободить эту память? Необходимо освобождать каждый `char`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) free(pointer[i]);
```

или достаточно

```
free(pointer);
```

одним вызовом функции `free`? Я склоняюсь ко второму варианту, поскольку значение `pointer[i]` из первого варианта не является указателем. Но откуда функция `free` знает, сколько памяти я выделил через `malloc`? Это где-то записано в оперативной памяти или здесь используется какая-то хитрость?

Comment: Я читал с приведением тестов и скринов, что malloc возвращает адрес. И если от этого адреса отнять 16 байт, прочитать int, то это и будет размер выделенного блока.

https://russianblogs.com/article/6889100669/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
free(pointer);
```

вполне достаточно. Диспетчер памяти сам разберется, сколько памяти освободить. Он хранит эту информацию где-то в своих внутренних структурах. Как именно - зависит от конкретной реализации.

Например, как вариант - вы запрашиваете `malloc`, при этом выделяется памяти *чуть больше* - ну, на какие-то, скажем, 4-8 байт, и вам возвращается указатель, смещенный на эти 4-8 байт, в которые менеджер записывает длину (и не только - если памяти выделить побольше:)). А при освобождении - он отсчитывает от переданного указателя нужное число байт и читает сохраненную информацию.

Еще раз - написанное не означает, что все сделано именно так, это всего лишь один из возможных вариантов. Как именно выделять память и где хранить служебную информацию - стандарт не определяет. Если вы хотите писать переносимые программы - вас это интересовать (для применения в своем коде) не должно...

Answer (score 4):

`malloc` поддерживает внутренную структуру, в которой хранит кроме прочего и размеры всех выделенных кусков памяти.

В `glibc` есть интерфейс для доступа к этой информации: `size_t malloc_usable_size(void*)`. Ну и вообще там много интересного: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Summary-of-Malloc.html#Summary-of-Malloc

Answer (score 1):

Процесс освобождения памяти должно "зеркально" соответствовать процессу его выделения. В данном случае вы выделяли память одним вызовом `malloc`. Значит освобождать вы ее будете одним вызовом `free`. Ни о каком "освобождать каждый char" не может быть и речи.

В традиционной реализации, `malloc` выделит больше памяти, чем вы запросили. В дополнительные байты памяти (обычно в начале выделенного блока) будет записан размер выделенного блока памяти

```
+-----+--------------------------     ----+
| 100 |                           ...     |
+-----+--------------------------     ----+
^  ^  ^
|  |  адрес, который `malloc` вернет вам в качестве результата
|  |
|  размер блока, записанный туда `malloc`
|
начало фактически выделенного `malloc` блока
```

Когда вы вызовете `free(pointer)`, функция `free` просто прочтает размер блока из области памяти "слева" от адреса `pointer` - так она узнает, сколько памяти нужно освободить. Вот и вся "хитрость".

Записанный размер может быть полным размером блока или полезным размером блока, а также может меняться в большую сторону из соображений выравнивания размеров блоков. Это все детали реализации, как, впрочем, и весь механизм.